# CasperJS can't access ReactJS shadow DOM

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I've been trying to wait and verify for a selector that was generated by `reactjs` (using shadow dom elements)

However, `casperjs` seems unable to locate the element I was trying to check. Is this an issue for CasperJS or maybe its engine PhantomJS?

I would like to know more about on how to handle this properly.

Here's some of my code

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.waitForSelector('#someid', function(){
        // found
    }, function(){
        // error - always go here
    }, 5000);
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you use?

Comment: phantomjs 1.9.2 using casperjs 1.1beta-3. Can this be resolve with higher version of phantomjs?

Comment: Maybe, try PhantomJS 2.

Comment: But phantomjs 2 is not compatible with casperjs 1.1beta-3. Any other workaround you recommend?

Comment: You can install CasperJS from git.

Comment: Have you tried it? Its still not working on my side.

Comment: No, I haven't. I don't know of any site that uses shadow dom (without a fallback). Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.